# Is there a way to get a data dump from Ektron

Tags: migration, ektron, data-dump

I need a way to get all of the data out of an Ektron site in any format, that I can use to import it into a new CMS. To my eyes the database is completely obfuscated and I'm not finding any good resources. I would be happy for links, tips, videos, angels, magic lamps or companies that will do it on the cheep. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the SQL database in the content_html table, I can get all of the content, which contains a tag for the "type" like book or song, but no taxonomy. Using localization export, I can get the data with some of the taxonomy, but not all and no content type.  What I need is a way to create a display that has all of the filtering features at once? Subject -- topic -- subtopic -- type  Thoughts? I have thought about scraping the existing site, but Ektron does not treat the scrapers well :)

Comment: **Update:** I was able to get the body data out of the content_html table in the SQL server and then create a usable version of the taxonomy by copying the menu. I am importing the code in two passes, first with the content and then adding the taxonomies. This approach seems to be working fine. Thank you all for you help and suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do Ektron migrations of this nature regularly for my company and the problem with such migrations is that there really is no "standard". Every site has it's data structured quite differently and this will be especially true of ektron sites that rely on smartforms, or ones that have complex metadata or taxonomy relationships. 
Your best bet will probably be to write a custom export tool to get your data into a format your target CMS can handle. If you are moving into another .net CMS, you might be well served by utilizing the ektron SOAP web services.

Comment: I would happily mine this stuff out of the database into a form I can use, but there does not seem to be a key to help track all of the data to all of the tables its stored on. This database is highly relational and there seems to be a lot of obfuscation as well or at least hashing.  I would be gratful for any help.

Comment: @DanielLefebvre You are absolutely correct - the Ektron DBs are extremely relational, which makes exporting "complete" data difficult at best. If your site is primarily plain text content, the "folder" and "content" tables are all you'll need and are straightforward enough, but anything more involved will be a massive headache trying to go through the DB. That is why I recommend writing a custom export tool that uses the Ektron APIs to get at your data.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that come to mind:

1. Perform database Backup (and Restore): "Backup" the Ektron database you are using and "Restore" it where you need it to go.  Both of these actions can be performed using SQL
   Server Management Studio with access to the filesystem on your
   database server.  This will restore ALL data EXACTLY as it was when
   backed up.  This is straight forward, but not flexible and I feel like this isn't
   what you're looking for.  If you want to treat "Ektron" like it's just any other database, then researching a more generic SQL Server Database "Dump" may be useful.
2. Perform content Export (and Import): Ektron provides a content export feature.  This can be found in the Workarea under [Settings] > [Localization].  The purpose behind the export is to translate/localize content into another language and then import it back into the CMS, but...  You aren't looking to localize your content as far as I can tell, but this export feature may still be of interest to you for whatever purpose you have in mind.

Comment: The localization feature will export into the XLIFF format and will include all content, menus and taxonomy, though not much else.

Comment: @MaxPRafferty is correct in that the export has it's limitations.   The export contains XLIFF which is really just XML, so it can be interpreted however you want.  The content import will also grab your uploaded files (not that you can't just grab those off the web server manually).