# Getting content out of Ektron in HTML or XML format for external use?

Tags: html, xml, ektron

Below are some questions bugging in my head for a long time,

1. Is there a tool to move the contents(data) from Ektron in XML or HTML format for external use. Move in the sense, converting everything into XML or HTML format.
2. If there is no tool to accomplish this,what are the other approaches i could go for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you searched for it? How long you've been using Ektron? Which version are you using? Ektron has it's own API and you can do all what you are asking and more...

Answer (score 1):

One thing that comes to mind:

*See original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435577/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-data-dump-from-ektron/21472610#21472610).*

Perform content Export (and Import): Ektron provides a content export feature. This can be found in the Workarea under **[Settings] > [Localization]**. The purpose behind the export is to translate/localize content and then import it back into the CMS into another language.

You aren't looking to localize your content as far as I can tell, but this export feature may still be of interest to you for whatever purpose you have in mind for the **XML** output.